# Solving Quartic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Could someone please explain how to solve this : $x^4+3x^3-6x^2+16x+56=0$ - not the answer only, but a step-by-step solution.

Comment: Your tags seem a bit inappropriate, what connection does this have with orthogonal polynomials?

Comment: You can go to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B3x%5E3-6x%5E2%2B16x%2B56%3D0&dataset=), click "step-by-step solution", and see.  The four roots are not very nice.  Two are real and two are complex.

Comment: @FRM I added an explicit example in case you want to try Ferrari's approach.

Answer (score 5):

All quartic equations can be solved with radicals,

See the following:

- http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html

If you don't want to follow that route I suggest the following. Put the polynomial in a calculator and look at the x-intercepts. If this is a homework problem one of those will be whole number or fraction. Then use long division to factor the polynomial further.

As an example if you plugged $9x^2-1=0$ into a calculator you would see it had an x-intercept at $x=0.33333333 \approx \frac{1}{3}$. Plugging $x=1/3$ into the equation would yield $0=0$ as expected. This tells us to divide by $x-\frac{1}{3}$, doing this will give a qoutient of $x+\frac{1}{3}$ which tells us the other root.

See: [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B%20x4%2b3x3%E2%88%926x2%2b16x%2b56%20==0,%20x%5D) for the actual roots which are disgustingly complicated.

---

I decided to add a example of using Ferrari's method to solve the quartic. However I will be solving a different quartic from the one posted.

Consider the equation below,

$$ x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$$

Our first step is to make the substitution $x=t-\frac{b}{4a}$ where b=1 and a=1.

$$ (t-\frac{1}{4})^4+(t-\frac{1}{4})^3+(t-\frac{1}{4})^2+(t-\frac{1}{4})+1=0$$

$$ t^4  + \frac{5}{8} t^2 +\frac{5}{8}t+\frac{205}{256} = 0 \qquad \text{(notice we lost } t^3)$$

Now push the linear term to the right hand side and complete the square on the left.

$$ t^4  + \frac{5}{8} t^2 +\frac{205}{256} = -\frac{5}{8}t$$

$$ (t^2+\frac{5}{16})^2 + 45/64 = -\frac{5}{8}t$$

$$ (t^2+\frac{5}{16})^2  = -\frac{5}{8}t - \frac{45}{64}$$

We now add and subtract an as yet unknown variable $z$ within the squared term.

$$ (t^2+\frac{5}{16}+z-z)^2  = -\frac{5}{8}t - \frac{45}{64}$$

Note that $(t^2+\frac{5}{16}+z-z)^2 = (t^2+\frac{5}{16}+z)^2 -2z(t^2+\frac{5}{16}+z)+z^2 = (t^2+\frac{5}{16}+z)^2 - 2z(t^2+\frac{5}{16})-z^2$

Putting this into our expression and isolating the perfect square we get,

$$ (t^2+\frac{5}{16}+z)^2  = -\frac{5}{8}t - \frac{45}{64}+2z(t^2+\frac{5}{16})+z^2$$

The left is a perfect square in the variable $t$. This motivates us to rewrite the right hand side in that form as well. Therefore we require that the discriminant $B^2-4AC$ be zero.

$$ A=2z, B=-\frac{5}{8}, C=z^2+\frac{5}{8}z-\frac{45}{64}$$

$$ \frac{25}{64} - 8z(z^2+\frac{5}{8}z-\frac{45}{64}) = 0 $$

$$ -8 z^3 -5 z^2 + \frac{45}{8} z + 25/64 = 0 $$

We need to find the $z$ which satisfy this equation. There is another formula (called cardono's formula) which can solve for these). Fortunately this polynomial has a [rational root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots%20of%2025/64%2b%2845%20z%29/8-5%20z%5E2-8%20z%5E3) of $z=5/8$.

We will put z=5/8 back into our original equation and get,

$$ (t^2+\frac{15}{16})^2  = 5/64-(5 t)/8+(5 t^2)/4$$

$$ (t^2+\frac{15}{16})^2  = \frac{5}{4}(t-\frac{1}{4})^2$$

Taking the square root of both sides we get,

$$ t^2+\frac{15}{16}  = \pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}t \mp \frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}$$

$$ t^2 \mp \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}t +\frac{15}{16} \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{8} = 0$$

And now applying the good old quadratic formula we get,

$$t = \frac{\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-4(\frac{15}{16} \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{8})} }{2}$$

One of these is,
$$ t = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+i \frac{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}{2\sqrt{2}} = e^{2\pi i/5} + \frac{1}{4}$$,

Recall that our original variable was $x=t-\frac{1}{4}$.

A solution to our original quartic is $x=e^{2 \pi i /5}$. Substituting this in the original gives,

$$ e^{8\pi i/5}+e^{6\pi i/5} + e^{4\pi i/5} + e^{2\pi i/5} + 1 = 0 $$

Which can be verified at [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20simplify%20e%5E%7B8%5Cpi%20i/5%7D%2be%5E%7B6%5Cpi%20i/5%7D%20%2b%20e%5E%7B4%5Cpi%20i/5%7D%20%2b%20e%5E%7B2%5Cpi%20i/5%7D%20%2b%201).

I pretty much just followed the instructions in my first link, but I thought it might be helpful to have another example.

Comment: The second method, though generally good advice, won't work here; all the roots are horrible.

Comment: I thought they might be. At least there are the explicit formulas provided by the links. It would be helpful if we knew the context in which this problem came up.

Answer (score 0):

Quartic equation has a number of different ways to be solved.

One is to write it as a function and to find it's zeroes using [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or some other zero-approximatization methods.

Another way is to use resolvents(radicals) to solve it. If you're begginer you'd have a little bit harder time with this, but the routine of solving quartic equation will come with time.

Also you could use [Ferrari's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#Ferrari.27s_solution) to transform this equation to a equation of third degree and then solve it using [Cardano's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano.27s_method). This is pretty simular to resolvent solution.

If a quartic equation has a rational solution, then it must be factor of the last coefficient. So you can check all its factor. If you find one then you can factorize it and reduce it to third degree polynomial, which are much easier to solve. Also you can repeat the process again and hopefully bring it to a second degree polynomial. This method is called [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Since the coefficient of the fourth power term is 1, let A=3, B=-6, C=16, and D=56.  These are just the remaining coefficients and constant term.  Now transform the quartic into the equivalent resolvent cubic

Y^3 - By^2 + (AC-4D)Y - A^2D + 4BD - C^2 = 0

Using the above values of A, B, C, and D, you should find that this reduces to Y^3 + 6Y^2 - 176Y - 2104 = 0.  Now, we need to find a solution to this cubic.

So for the time being, redefine A, B, C, and D to be the coefficients and constant term of this cubic...A is 1, B is 6, C is -176 and D is -2104.  Calculate (3C/A) - (B^2/A^2) and divide the difference by 3.  Call the result F.  In this case F = -188.  Now calculate (2B^3/A^3) - (9BC/A^2) + (27D/A) and divide the result by 27.  Call the result G.  Here, G is -1736.  Now calculate (G^2/4) + (F^3/27) and call the result H.  Here, H = 507325.0370.

Since H is positive, the cubic has only one real root.  Define R as (-G/2) + sqrt(H).  Define S as the cube root of R.  Define T as (-G/2) - sqrt(H) and U as the cube root of T.  Here, R = 1580.267532, S = 11.64779019, T = 155.7324681, and U = 5.38013354.  A solution to the resolvent cubic is now given by

X1 = (S+U) - (B/3A), or approximately 15.02792373.

Now go back to the values of A, B, C, and D for the quartic equation and define Y as the root of the resolvent cubic we just found. Take the square root of (A^2/4 - B + Y) and call it R.

Now, calculate 3A^2/4 - R^2 - 2B + (4AB - 8C - A^3)/4R.  Take the square root of this and call it D.  Take 3A^2/4 - R^2 - 2B - (4AB - 8C - A^3)/4R, then find the square root of this and call it E.

The four roots of the quartic can now be expressed as:

1) (-A/4) + (R/2) + (D/2)

2) (-A/4) + (R/2) - (D/2)

3) (-A/4) - (R/2) + (E/2)

4) (-A/4) - (R/2) - (E/2)

In this case, they are approximately -1.81751644, -4.50720359, and 1.66236004 +/- 2.01805997i.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please use Mathjax syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it.  By all means delete the post if it's not up to standards...I was just trying to help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation